# В Android Studio при создании нового проекта зависает процесс

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Добрый день. Просьба помочь с проблемой - В Android Studio при создании нового проекта зависает процесс выгрузки на одном из двух окнах:
 Gradle: Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-login/commons-login/... 
 (при работе под правами пользователя)

Gradle: Download http://repo1.maven,org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-par....
 (при работе под правами админа)

p.s. 
- Переменная среды Java_Home установлена
- установленная OC - Windows 7 (64 разряда)

Comment: ссылки не пашут...

Answer (score 1):

Самое главное- Android Studio еще очень сырой,об этом сами разработчики предупреждают. В данный момент студия просто напичкана большим количеством разнообразных багов (в основном мелких, но от этого не менее неприятных),а любому программисту нужна стабильная среда разработки,такая как Intellij Idea например. Так вот, до релиза студии советую вам ее использовать, берегите свои нервные клетки :)